# Store class information of an interface in a hashmap, and create instance of that later

Tags: java

I want to make a `HashMap` with `String` as key, and a value that represents a class that implements `ICommand`. I want to do this as I want to get a command as a string, check if that command exists (is loaded in the `HashMap`), create an instance of that command, and run it. I am aware of `Type` but `Type` can represent any kind of class, and not something that implements my interface. I have the following so far:

I know I can use switch but it is ugly and will probably add custom commands later.

```
public class Commands
{
    // will register commands later
    HashMap<String, Type> _commands;
    public void parseCommand(String command)
    {
        String[] args = command.split("\\s+");
        if (args.length > 0 && _commands.containsKey(args[0]))
        {
            // should create instance of _commands[args[0]] here
        }
    }

    // will load commands dynamically later
    public interface ICommand
    {
        public String getCommandName();
        public void execute(String args);
        //public void printHelp();
    }

    public class HelpCommand implements ICommand
    {
        public String getCommandName()
        {
            return "help";
        }
        public void execute(String args)
        {
            System.out.println("help - print help");
            System.out.println("exit - quit the server");
            System.out.println("register username password - creates user");
        }

    }

    public class ExitCommand implements ICommand
    {
        public String getCommandName()
        {
            return "exit";
        }
        public void execute(String args)
        {
            // todo save state, log out users, etc.
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by value that represents a class?Are u talking about instance of class or the Class itself?

Comment: @KumarAbhinav I don't want to create an instance of a command, I want to store the information of that command so I can create an instance of that thing later.

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, Class<? extends ICommand>> map;
Class<? extends ICommand> type = map.get("someCommand");
ICommand command = type.newInstance();
command.execute();
```

Sounds like you should store `Class` instead of `Type`. By limiting the Map to hold instances of `Class` that extend `ICommand` I believe you have what you want.

All of the above aside, you might want to consider storing factories instance of Class instances. `interface ICommandFactory { ICommand createNewInstance();}`.

Per `Pacha` you add instances of class with `map.put("someKey", SomeConcreteClass.class);`

Comment: Oh, thanks. How do I load my class on that map? Using the `instanceof` operator? Also, very helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: Reflection is good but can it handle the cases where the implementor of the class does not have a no-arg constructor or any interface which extends ICommand..I think a lot of exception handling wil go

Comment: @Pacha - You can use expressions like `_commands.put("key", ConcreteCommandClass.class);` to initialize the map.